# Flag a closed question for removal?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, flagging

I just came across a question that looks to me like the intention was to remove it last November:

[to be deleted - question [closed] [closed]](https://serverfault.com/q/203575/86976) (**edit**: meanwhile removed)

Having less than 10k rep, should I flag this question?
Would `very low quality` be a good flag reason?
It looks to me like this question is "unlikely to be salvageable through editing."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag as mod attention, and just enter some descriptive text as to why you think it should be deleted. Otherwise, if we see "low quality" and that it's already closed, we're likely to dismiss the flag, as we don't always have the time to review the entire post contents; although that one would be pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll do so next time.

Comment: +1 Unless "very low quality" is an exact description of the problem, please fill in a few words on why it *needs* someone to look at it.